# What is the data type of X in pca.fit_transform(X)?

Tags: scikit-learn, pca, gensim, word2vec

I got a word2vec model `abuse_model` trained by Gensim. I want to apply PCA and make a plot on CERTAIN words that I only care about (vs. all words in the model). Therefore, I created a dict `d` whose keys are words that I care about and the values are vectors to the key.

```
vocab = list(abuse_model.wv.key_to_index)
vocab = [v for v in vocab if v in positive_terms]
d = {}
for word in vocab:
    d[word] = abuse_model.wv[word]
```

No errors so far.

I encountered an error when passing the dict into `pca.fit_transform`. I'm new to it and am wondering if the data format that I passed in (list of tuples) is not correct. What data type that the argument has to be?

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
result = pca.fit_transform(list(d.items()))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per `scikit-learn` docs – https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit_transform – the argument to `.fit_transform()`, as is usual for `scikit-learn` models, is "array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)".

Here, that'd mean your samples/rows are words, and features/columns the word-vector dimensions. And, you'll want to remember *outside* of the `PCA` object which words correspond to which rows. (In Python 3.x, the fact your `d` `dict` will always iterate in the order of insertion should have you covered there.)

So, it may be enough to change your use of `.items()` to `.values()`, so that you wind up supplying `PCA` with your `list` (which is suitably array-like) of vectors.

A few other notes:

- the `.key_to_index` property is already a `list`, so you don't need to convert/copy it
- if your `positive_terms` is a large `list`, changing it to a `set` could offer faster `in` membership-testing
- rather than using a `d` `dict`, which involves a little more overhead (including when you then make a `list` of its values), if your sets-of-words and vectors are large, you might want to preallocate a `numpy` array of the right size and collect your vectors in it. For example:

```py
X = np.empty((len(vocab), abuse_model.wv.vector_size)
for i, word in enumerate(vocab):
    X[i] = abuse_model.wv[word]

#...
#...

result = pca.fit_transform(X)
```

- Even though your hunch is you only want the dimensionality-reduction on your subset of words, you may also want to try keeping all words, or some random subset of other words – it *might* help retain some of the original structure that otherwise, your subsampling will have prematurely removed. (Unsure of this; just noting it could be a factor.) Even if you do the PCA on a larger set of words, you could still choose to only later plot/analyze your desired subset for clarity.